# Send messages through Signal - Private Messenger from a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way or API to be able to send messages through Signal Private Messenger originating from a Rails application?  I'm thinking of how to technically do this.

I use signal's desktop app, synchronized to my phone all of the time.  I'm trying to figure out if I could automate some of this activity to have a Rails application send messages through Signal.

The rails app runs in an ubuntu server environment.  Without using an API, I might could interface with the desktop app somehow.  Looking on the signal developer page, there is a Javascript library.

Everything I have searched seems to point to onesignal, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for.

Has anyone attempted to do this?

Update:  Looking into Signal-CLI.  Any success using this?